# Android:Deleting duplicates from Playlist

Tags: android, playlist, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to remove duplicate songs from a playlist. This is the code which I'm using to remove a song from playlist.

```
public static void removeFromPlaylist(final Context context, final long id,
            final long playlistId) {
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        int del = resolver.delete(uri, Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID + " = ? ", new String[] {
            Long.toString(id)
        });
        Log.e("DeleteFromPlaylist",""+del);
    }
```

But the problem here is that it'll remove all the songs. Let's say I added 'SongOne' 3 times in a playlist Playlist1. When I do remove 'SongOne' should be removed only once, but here all the 3 'SongOne' gets removed. I get '3' in the Log. So what modifications should i do to the code such that `ContentResolver.delete()` deletes only once?

Thanks!

Comment: because you deleted one song with songId that is duplicate, this delete all song with that id, you can insert that song after deleting or you can get row id of those and delete those with id

Comment: Can you elaborate on getting the rowId and deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following code, this is not full code you need test that because I don't have any IDE in this area.

```
   final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playlistId);
   final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
   Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri,null , Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID + " = ? ", new String[] {
        Long.toString(id)} , null , null ); 

 List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
 if (cursor != null)
    while ( cursor.moveToNext())
    {
      ids.add ( cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"))); // you need get id of song, this might be id

    }

for (int i = 1 ; i < ids.size() ; i++) // skip first index in list
     resolver.delete(uri, "id" + " = ? ", new String[] {
        Long.toString(ids.get(i)) });
```

Comment: Perfect. Had to modify little as you said. Also, I didn't use the for loop 'cuz I wanted to remove only one item. So I just did ids.get(0). But a drawback being if I delete the 3rd item on the playlist, on the UI it'll delete the first item.

Comment: glad to help @PsyGik if you think your modification is important you can edit my post